# Does ping <hostname> only search on same subnet?

Tags: networking

I'm with tech support and he's trying to ping our server (on my machine through teamviewer). I assume he thinks the two machines are on the same subnet because he uses `ping <hostname>` when it is possible that multiple machines could have the same hostname. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Ping uses the name resolutions you have configured on your system.

Since you mentioned teamviewer, I could possibly assume Windows which supports DNS, WINS, hosts file which all have no limitations for a single subnet.  But there are also a couple broadcast based name resolution methods that only work on the local subnet.  What actually is being used completely depends on your configuration.

> when it is possible that multiple machines could have the same hostname.

Lots of silly configurations are possible.  Having two hosts with the same fully qualified host name on the same network would almost certainly be a bad configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Ping will use whatever you've configured as a name resolution system. For Windows machines, by default the system will also look for WINS resolution which by itself will recognize computers by name which are inside the same subnet and in the same workgroup, and that's probably why you're asking that.

For Linux/UNIX machines, that's not enabled by default, and name resolution order is defined by the /etc/host.conf in older systems. DNS servers are defined depending of which Linux distribution you're using.

Hope that helps.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding each other, and they are likely relying on information other then that you have discerned (or they just don't know what they are talking about)

(S)he is most likely using "ping "  where hostname has no "." in it, and this means it is likely responding on a local machine.   That said, this is by no means a given, as your OS may append a domain name based on your DNS settings.

There are a couple of other things they could be looking at as well - the first is the IP address resolved.  If it starts 192.168, 10. or 172.[16-31] it is space set aside for internal networks, and they could have used recognised that.  It is also possible that they saw a TTL value for each ping, and concluded based on that number that the system was 1 hop away, ie on your LAN.

It is possible for multiple machines to have the same hostname, however, generally, whatever ping thinks is correct is going to be authorative as its using a system call, and that is what the system thinks too.